# Hozirontally centered column in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, center

I am trying to do centering and text sizing in tabularx environment using the following definitions:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

I'm then using a tabularx environmment, but all my cell are indeed vertically centered, but not horizontally.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
Réactifs & CAS & Stock & MW (g/mol) & m (g) & V (mL) & n (mmol) & n eq & d  \\
\hline
 Pomalidominde PEG2 butyl azide & 123-256-3 & CG3-454F1 & 500,51 & 0,00233 & XXXX & 0,047 & 1,3 & 1,12 \\
\hline
```

\end{tabularx}

Here is the result :

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please aplly this checklist to your posted code to improve it: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 ? Thank you

Comment: The code you show does horizontal centering as your image shows. `X` columns by default use `p` column type which top aligns on the first line, you can use `m` by setting  `\tabularxcolumn`

Comment: @MS-SPO, I think I check all the boxes no, tell me what looks unclear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm triyng it by adding : `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` but all I get is an Missing $ inserted and Extra }, or forgotten $ error

Comment: no  use `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}`  then add `\centering` as you were doing previously

Comment: @Juju, what's about 3.1, `documentclass` and all the others? E.g. `1 it does compile`. Etc. etc.